# ruby creating csv file with different multiple colums using arrays

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am beginner and working on ruby.

I have several arrays and I want to write them into a csv file. I want each array to correspond a column in the csv file when we open it via excel.

```
array1 = ["a","b", .......]
array2 = ["1","2", .......]
array3 = ["11","22", .......]

headers = ["letter","number","numberagain",.....]

all = [[array1],[array2],[array3]]

File.open('abc.csv','w') do |f|
 f.write(headers.join("\n"))
 f.write(all.join("\n"))
end
```

In this code it all seems in the same column. How can I make it look pretty in excel?

Current
[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NejOt.png)

What I am trying to get
[wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7cGh.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
array1 = ["a","b"]
array2 = ["1","2"]
array3 = ["11","22"]

headers = ["letter","number","numberagain"]

#not [[array1],...]; array1 is an Array already:
all = [array1, array2, array3].transpose.map{|row| row.join(",")}
# transpose turns cols into rows; join turns each row into a string.
# map takes all those strings and puts them in an Array

File.open('abc.csv','w') do |f|
  f.puts(headers.join(",")) #same as f.puts("letter,number,numberagain")
  f.puts all
end
```

Some explanation is in the comments in the code.